# Excluding program feature while compiling with make command

Tags: shell, makefile, build, debian

I'm trying to use Gentoo Linux's USE flag feature on a Debian based system.
After I obtained the source code with apt-get source, I want to give an environment variable that excludes some unneeded features on the compiled program like how you define in Gentoo Linux USE="-foo -bar" for example.

Is it possible for every package (because I'm planning to automatize something, not for just one package) that I can download through apt-get source, or is this a Gentoo specific feature?

Comment: Although certainly not robust, it may be worth using a CONFIG_SITE.  That is, create the file /usr/local/share/config.site and include lines like `USE='-foo -bar'`  Any package you subsequently build that uses an autoconf generated configure script will read /usr/local/share/config.site  and make the assignments you are asking for.  (But it will actually read $CONFIG_SITE or ${prefix}/share/config.site, so you may want to add /usr/share/config.site)  As I said, not robust, but perhaps worth exploring

Comment: `USE` is a Gentoo feature.  You can't use it with other distros.  If you want to disable some feature you need to examine the package you are trying to build and determine how to do that for that package.

Answer (score 0):

Gentoo is very different from Debian and its derivatives.  One of Gentoo's distinguishing characteristics is that its package manager, Portage, performs a custom local build of each package it installs.  `USE` is a feature of Portage, and it makes sense only that or a similar context, because it influences those local builds.

On the other hand, Debian's package-management system, Apt, is organized around installing pre-built binary packages.  USE does not make sense there, because pre-building packages precludes those packages being modulated by local settings.  Systems that use this kind of package management approach either pre-select package options at the Linux distribution level or split optional features out into their own packages.  Generally speaking, they also have dependency-management features to help avoid missing dependencies when you install a package.

> Is it possible for every package [...] that I can download through apt-get source, or is this a Gentoo specific feature?

`USE` is specific to Portage. That's not the same as being specific to Gentoo (other Linux distributions use it too), but it does mean that it is not a Debian feature.  On Debian, I urge you to use the distro's standard (binary) packages via `apt install` / `apt upgrade`, rather than downloading sources and building locally.  This will be faster, easier, and more reliable, and it will tend to provide better system stability, too.